# How can I disable HUD using a console command?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way a fast way to disable HUD, using a console command? I would like to remove it to do better in-game screenshot.

Comment: The hud is poorly done. They should of had opacity sliders for each hud item instead of all. I would love to get rid of the compass and leave the crosshairs up but you can't do that because everything is tied to the main slider. So dumb. I hate the fact that you can't shut off the quest arrow indicators. That feature ruins the sense of exploring to find the objective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Entering `toggleMenus` (or just `tm`) into the console will toggle the HUD's visibility. Beware that it also makes the console invisible!

Comment: It works, but the game crashes after few seconds. Do you have this problem too?

Comment: I have not. The only issue I had was not realizing that the console window was open but not displaying after entering the command.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to turn off the HUD is to turn the HUD opacity all the way down in the display menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is a mod called iHUD you can find it with google or at Nexus.. It has options for keeping cross hair and fade options for about everything...

I'm trying to find a way to temp get rid of all the activate hud: The push E to talk to do things

Answer (score -3):

You are looking for the [Immersive HUD mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/3222/?).